# Customize search_filter($query) function

Tags: search

I need to setup with this code BUT **it doesn’t work**.

**What I need to do:**
I need to setup the search engine so it shows the posts of the category “my zen” and all the forums (bbPress).

```
function search_filter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
         $query->set('post_type', array('post','forums'));
     $query->set('category_name', 'my-zen');
     $query->set('orderby', 'type');
         $query->set('order', 'ASC');
        
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

The result is “There has been a critical error on this website”.
Can you help me? Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you put the code?

Comment: Normally, I use snippets to write PHP code such as the CODE SNIPPETS plugin. This Error is something about mixed search types, I think.
For example, this function is OK. There isn't any critical error.
function search_filter( $query ) {
  if ($query->is_search() && !is_admin() ) {
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');

Comment: I don’t see any obvious problems that would cause a fatal error. The most likely reason would therefore be that you have another function named `search_filter`, causing a conflict, or that you’re missing php tags, or they’re in the wrong place.

Comment: For example, this function is OK. There isn't any critical error. function search_filter( $query ) { if ($query->is_search() && !is_admin() ) { } } add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter'); is it incorrect the function?

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I have changed  $query->set('orderby', 'type')

```
function search_filter($query) {
     if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
         $query->set('post_type', array('post','forums'));
         $query->set('category_name', 'my-zen');
         $query->set('orderby', 'date');
         $query->set('order', 'ASC');
            
        }
        return $query;
    }
add_filter('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Now, I don't have any Error critical, **but it doesn't work**. What is wrong in my code?